# Eloquent way to format string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, ruby-1.9.3

```
str = 'foo_bar    baz  __goo'
```

Should print as

```
Foo Bar Baz Goo
```

Tried to use `split /(\s|_)/`, but it returns `'_'` and `' '` and multiple spaces...?

Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean `/(\s|_)/` (direction of the slashes matters!), your regular expression is pretty close.  The reason you're getting the delimiters (spaces and underscores) in your result is the parentheses: they instruct the splitter to include the delimiters in the returned array.

The reason you are getting extra empty strings is that you are splitting on `\s`, which matches exactly one space (or tab), or '_', which matches exactly one underscore.  If you want to treat any number of spaces or underscores as a single delimiter, you need to add `+` to your regex - it means "one or more of the previous thing".

But `\s|_+` means "a space, or one or more underscores".  You want to apply the `+` to the whole expression, not just the `_`.  That brings us back to the parentheses.  In this case, you want to group the two alternatives together without capturing (and returning) them; the syntax for that is `(?:...)`.  So this is the result:

```
str.split(/(?:\s|_)+/)
```

Now, if you want to normalize case, you want to run `capitalize` on each string, which you can do with `map`, like this:

```
str.split(/(?:\s|_)+/).map { |s| s.capitalize }
```

or use the shortcut:

```
str.split(/(?:\s|_)+/).map(&:capitalize)
```

So far, all these solutions return an array of strings, which you can do a variety of things with.  But if you just want to put them back together into a single string, you can use `join`.  For instance, to put them together with a single space between them:

```
str.split(/(?:\s|_)+/).map(&:capitalize).join ' '
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
str.split(/[\s_]+/).map(&:classify).join(" ")
```

if you have access to active support, or

```
str.split(/[\s_]+/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
```

if you want plain ruby.

Comment: Why would you prefer classify to capitalize, even if you have activesupport?

Comment: `capitalize` is simpler, lacks un-necessary complexity. `classify` seems to use `camelize` and `singularize` internally. `titleize` from active support too internally uses `capitalize` along with two more functions.

Comment: classify is part of the activesupport api. If the example stated above is used in the Rails context specifically for the case of accessing classes, I would use classify anyways, because of this case: "account_user".classify => "AccountUser". "account_user".capitalize => "Account_user". If this is not the purpose of the example, then I would use plain ruby, capitalize, which is anyway lighter.

Comment: so, was the response any helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting the string on:

```
[\s_]+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `/[\ _]+/`, it looks for one or more occurrence or space or underscore. In that way it is able to eat out multiple underscores, spaces or a combination of both. After than you get an array, so you use `map` to transform each of them. Later you can get them together using `join`. See examples -

Get them in a list -

```
str.split(/[\ _]+/).map {|s| s.capitalize }
 => ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Goo"]
```

Get them as a whole string -

```
str.split(/[\ _]+/).map {|s| s.capitalize }.join(" ")
 => "Foo Bar Baz Goo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the pure Ruby version:

```
str = 'foo_bar    baz  __goo'
str.split(/[ _]+/).map{|s| s[0].upcase+s[1..-1]}.join(" ")
```